# Marker animation working in Chrome browser and not in Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari

How do I make the below animation fully work in safari browser ? It is working fine in Chrome.
Open the below link in chrome to see its full functionality (bounce and pulse effect), and in Safari to see the issue. Pulse effect around the pin doesn't work in safari!! 
How can I fix this ?

Here is [the JS FIDDLE link](http://jsfiddle.net/Falcon9/MNhNk/)

html code:

```
<div class='pin bounce'></div>
<div class='pulse'></div>
```

CSS code:

```
body {
  background: #e6e6e6;
}

.pin {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
  background: #00cae9;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
}
.pin:after {
  content: "";
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: 8px 0 0 8px;
  background: #e6e6e6;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.bounce {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
}

.pulse {
  background: #d6d4d4;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: 11px 0px 0px -12px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(55deg);
  z-index: -2;
}
.pulse:after {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -13px 0 0 -13px;
  -webkit-animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 2px #00cae9;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 1.1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-2000px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(30px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: That jsFiddle example worked in Safari for me.

Comment: Do you also see the continuous pulse effect around the pin after the pin had bounced ?

Comment: Yes - I saw the same thing in both Chrome and Safari. What OS/versions are you using?

Comment: Works in safari version 7 thanks !!